# Facebook login Button text not change

Tags: android, xml, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using facebook sdk for android, and implemented successfully.

1. Now i want to customize login button below  in my xml code -

and below is my  fb_bg.xml -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<solid android:color="@color/blue_fb" />

<corners android:radius="@dimen/space_mid10" />

<padding
    android:bottom="@dimen/space_mid6"
    android:left="@dimen/space_mid6"
    android:right="@dimen/space_mid6"
    android:top="@dimen/space_mid6" />

<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="@color/blue_fb" />
```

and code in my activity -

```
        mFbLoginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.fb_login_button);
        mFbLoginButton.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null,null, null);
        mFbLoginButton.setText("SIGN IN WITH FACEBOOK");
        mFbLoginButton.setTextSize(14);
```

but when run app , only button color is change  and no text display on button.

2. When user click fb button it redirects to facebook and after success full login button text change to logout.
   I dont want to show logouut text.

Please provide solution to my problem.
I have tried but nothing is working.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you want the default blue FB login button (with same look and feel of the fb login button), it is already available through fb-sdk. Just use it :)
2. For not wanting to show the logout button, you can always

   setVisibility(View.GONE)

on your Facebook button handle.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i am using facebook sdk but want to customize size of button with rounded corner on it. Also can not hide button, it should be visible thoroughly.

Comment: Ahh I get your point, then make a custom button which meets requirements and trigger the LoginManager login mechanism inside the onClick of that button, Update the button as per your requirements once login succeeds or fails.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks dude, you save my life.

Comment: @Ravi glad to hear that it helped you :)